# Filter out angular1 object with certan id using ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to not show some data from Firebase-db with ngrepeat using filter.

```
   [$add: function, $save: function, $remove: function, $keyAt: function, $indexFor: function…]
0: Object
1: Object
 $$hashKey: "object:31"
 $id: "forad"
 $priority: null
      info: Object
            namn: "John Doe"
            plats: 1





 <ion-item ng-repeat="l in notes | filter:{ 'id': forad }" class="note-listing">

   <h1>Den {{l.lokal[0].datum}} är lokalen bokad av {{l.lokal[0].namn}}</h1>
   <h3> {{l.info.plats}}.  {{l.info.namn}}</h3>

  </ion-item>
```

I wnat to filter out the  so that it doesnt get ittarated by ngRepeat and show on screen

Comment: I would pre-filter this data before passing to `ng-repeat` - better performance.

Comment: I tried but i didnt make it since i am using ald version of firebase binding

Answer (score 0):

If pre-filter is not possible then you can also something like below:

In Controller or Component:

```
$scope.filter = function(l){
  //return true or false based on your condition
}


<ion-item ng-show="filter(l)" ng-repeat="l in notes" class="note-listing">

   <h1>Den {{l.lokal[0].datum}} är lokalen bokad av {{l.lokal[0].namn}}</h1>
   <h3> {{l.info.plats}}.  {{l.info.namn}}</h3>

 </ion-item>
```

You can use ng-if as well instead of ng-show to remove iteration from dom.